# How to use list data in .cshtml file without using Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This question might be very basic but i'm very new to C#.I am returning list data from controller without using model. I want to use this and want to create a table.

```html
      // Mycontroller
        public ActionResult Applied( string id)
        {
            try {
                List<GrindersForJob> Grinders = JobAppliedRepository.GetgrindersByJobId(id);
                return View(Grinders);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return View();
            }
           

        }
```

Comment: Well you could use ViewBag but I wouldn't recommend that approach. Why would you not want to use a model?

Comment: `return View(Grinders)` _is_ using the model, all you need to do is add `@model List<GrindersForJob>` at the top of the .cshtml file and you can access it in the Razor code

Comment: How would I use for loop with viewbag?

Comment: @AnilSharma - I think you can cast the contents to a list. But do what markpsmith said if you dont want to encapsulate your list in a model class

Answer (score 0):

cshtml file =

```
@model IEnumerable<GrindersForJob>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @foreach(GrindersForJob item in Model)
        {
           <span>
               @item.YourColumnName
           </span>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's showing me : 
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: 1-Check that the list is empty

If it does not work, this code add to web.config file

<system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

Answer (score 0):

Just send the list to your view

At the top of the view add

```
@model IEnumerable<GrindersForJob>
```

Now you can iterate over this list in the view using `foreach` loop

Comment: I am using the same

Comment: and? are you facing any problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a list for a table why don't you just pass it in as a table?

As already mentioned @model IEnumerable will take your List

But if you need a table you can pass a DataTable to your view.

@model System.Data.DataTable